# Adding a share link straight to wall, into an email newsletter

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, newsletter

Wondering if anyone has actually managed to get the "share" functionality working in an email newsletter. 
Currently being asked by a client to "share" a certain part of a newsletter directly to a persons wall. 
However, the HTML will be generated by 1 program, and then a copy and paste into the email blaster to be sent.

Essentially, wondering can it be done? Are there any examples?

Comment: what are you wanting to do? post to a users wall? send them an email?  It is not so clear from your question...

Answer (score 0):

The like button plugin will work for a web page, not content in an email.
The share is being deprecated.
The send button plugin is used to share a URL (which is not content of an email).

I would suggest that the html of the email being blasted also be hosted on a web page.  Then have that like (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) button's (that is being send via email) set it's href property to that of the hosted web page.  That should work well.

Happy coding!